# Why is my Entity Framework object duplicating?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two classes that I have simplified for this SO question. Whenever I add a new 'parent' and attach existing 'child' entities, I end up with duplicated children. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public class Group
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Child ChildOne { get; set; }
    public virtual Child ChildTwo { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
}
using (var context = new RPSContext())
{
    Child childOne = context.Child.Where(p => p.Available == true).OrderBy(p => p.ChildId).FirstOrDefault();
    Child childTwo = context.Child.Where(p => p.Available == true).OrderBy(p => p.ChildId).Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
}
Parent parent = new Models.Parent;
parent.ChildOne = childOne;
parent.ChildTwo = childTwo;

using (var context = new RPSContext())
        {
            context.Parent.Add(parent);
            parent.ChildOne.Available = false;
            parent.ChildTwo.Available = false;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I hope I didn't make any errors when I simplified this code. Can anyone assist?

Comment: I guess by `Parent` you mean `Group`. And you get two new `Child` records created?

Comment: Yes, it is really a one to many relationship. Parent/Child is the wrong term, but I do get multiples of the children objects.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is some context nonsense going on here. Can you refactor this so you only have one `new RPSContext`?

Comment: I tried that with the same result.

Comment: Try performing in single context. You are fetching childOne and childTwo in one context which is disposed immediately after fetching it. So you might need to attach these two child entities in the new context OR perform both operations in the same context so that child entities gets related instead of getting added

Comment: Also why is this code not throwing error? Aint that `parent.Child...` be throwing error being the `parent` not initialized?

Comment: Are you moving the child items from an existing parent to the newly added parent?

Comment: @Developer - I missed putting in the 'new' line when simplifying the code. I will correct that.

Comment: @reckface - No. This is a 1 to many relationship. A 'child' can belong to more than one parent. Yeah, I know I used the wrong term (parent/child), (group/member) might be better.

Comment: You have to `Attach` them to the new context, so it knows they are existing entities. Otherwise it assumes they are new and is adding them to the database.

Comment: Try attaching the child entities in the second context using block before save changes. `context.Child.Attach(childOne);context.Child.Attach(childTwo);`

Comment: Thank you to Ivan and Developer. Attaching is what I needed to do. Not sure if I can give you credit since you just added a comment, but if you want to add an answer I will go ahead and accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try performing in single context. You are fetching childOne and childTwo in one context which is disposed immediately after fetching it.

So you might need to attach these two child entities in the new context 
`context.Child.Attach(childOne);context.Child.Attach(childTwo‌​);`

OR perform both operations in the same context so that child entities gets related instead of getting added

Comment: I found that combining into one context had no impact, but attaching did. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln did you omit a .AsNoTracking from the code you copied for this question? If combining into a single context didn't fix it, then you're loading the Child entities in a way that's different from "normal"

Comment: @Vlad274 - thats true.. something that works with attach should also work in the same context IMO unless tracking is explicitly disabled